# Changing the locale in Arch

Tags: linux, locale, archlinux

My gnome-terminal is broken, so is zim and many other programs, the xfce-terminal does not show characters like ö ä or ü. All of them show problems with the locale. I think the problems stems from ill-configured locale settings. For typing "locale" the xfce4-terminal prompts

```
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC=aa_DJ.UTF-8
LC_TIME=aa_DJ.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY=aa_DJ.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER=aa_DJ.UTF-8
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT=aa_DJ.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

This is not what I want. My /etc/locale.conf is set to

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

My /etc/locale.gen is uncommented such executing "locale-gen" prompts

```
de_DE.UTF-8... done
de_DE.ISO-8859-1... done
en_US.UTF-8... done
en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
```

When looking at the environment variables my "locale" produces, it doesn't wonder me too much, that nothing is working as supposed. I don't know why there is "aa_DJ" in these variables, I don't know the language (to be precise, I am not sure which language that is, maybe I speak it ...). However, I really don't know where to change the environment variable permanently (Without putting it in .bashrc) . I tried grepping it in my home folder and after that in root (Recursive on --> grep looked everywhere), but I couldn't find anything.

So my question is: Where or how are these variables defined and how can I change them? I can't find anything that explains it to me. I am aware that there are several people asking similar questions, I tried those solutions but they seem to have different problems (or they solve it with hacking something into .bashrc, which doesn't do the trick here and is not a very meaningful way).

Comment: As I found out now, I missed to give an information that might have been useful. I use the gnome3 desktop env. Gnome3 has its own setting for the locales that overwrites the system standard (and is not saved in plain text, I assume, otherwise I should have found it with grep). The solution was to correct the gnome setting via 

    gsettings get org.gnome.system.locale region 'de_DE.UTF-8'

Answer (score 2):

So, the locale you have there seems to be:

```
Afar - DJIBOUTI (DJ) (aa_DJ)
```

So, after running `locale-gen` you need to run `localectl list-locales` and identify the locale you need.

Finally run:

```
localectl set-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

NOTE: The German page for locale in Arch linux seems to be outdated

Answer (score 0):

As I found out now, I missed to give an information that might have been useful and which helped me to solve the question. I use the gnome3 desktop env. Gnome3 has its own setting for the locales that overwrites the system standard (and is not saved in plain text I assume, otherwise I should have found it with grep). The solution was to correct the gnome setting via

```
gsettings get org.gnome.system.locale region 'de_DE.UTF-8'
```